# Kernel of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been asked to find the kernel of the plane: $x+y+z = 0$.

The answer I got was $[-1,1,0] , [-1,0,1]$.

The correct answer is $[1,-1,0] , [1,0,-1]$.

I'm confused why this is. This makes it appear that the non free variables are in terms of the free variables instead of the opposite.

Comment: The vector basis specifying the kernel is not unique. The two vectors you listed span the same subspace as the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem asked you to find the kernel of the map $$(x,y,z)\rightarrow x+y+z$$ as a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Since the image is one dimensional, the kernel is 2 dimensional and must be spanned by two linearly independent vectors. You can make easy choices like $$(a,-a,0),(0,b,-b),(c,0,-c),(a,b,-a-b)...$$
as long as the two vectors are not linearly dependent on each other. There is probably no canonical choice for such a basis unless you specify other conditions.